# How get form by name in $scope?

Tags: angularjs

How to get form by name in $scope?

Test example:

```
<div ng-controller="solod">
  <form name="good_f">
   <input type="text" name="super">
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  function solod($scope){
    console.log($scope.good_f) //undefined 
  }
</script>
```

Is it possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You usually don't want the controller to access the form like this, that's coupling the controller to the structure of the view too tightly. Instead, pass the form to the controller like this...

```
<div ng-controller="solod">
  <form name="good_f" ng-submit="submit(good_f)">
   <input type="text" name="super">
  </form>
</div>



 <script> 
  function solod($scope){
    $scope.submit = function(theForm){
          console.log(theForm)// not undefined 
          console.log($scope.good_f) // will exist now also
    };

    // do stuff in a watch
    $scope.$watch("good_f", function(formVal){ console.log(formVal);});
  }
  </script>
```

Otherwise, if you just want to track the value of the text input, give it an `ng-model`

Edit: 
On further research, $scope will have good_f as a property, just not when you're logging it in the constructor. You could set up a watch on good_f if you wanted, but I still think you should pass it in.

> name (optional) string Name of the form. If specified, the form
>   controller will be published into related scope, under this name.
>
> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

Answer (score 4):

Another possible way is to use `ng-form`, this will help you to access the form via scope easily.

```
<div ng-controller="solod">
  <ng-form name="good_f">
   <input type="text" name="super">
  </ng-form>
</div>
```

Script code in your controller:

**EDIT**:
As JeremyWeir mentioned, to solve your problem you can use `$timeout` service of angularjs

```
 function solod($scope){
    $timeout(function(){
      console.log($scope.good_f);
    });
 }
```

Comment: Pretty sure he'll have the same timing issues with ng-form http://jsbin.com/jaquboruyuwi/1/edit

Comment: @JeremyWeir Thanks for pointing out, i didn't even think of it.. :(

Answer (score 2):

> Caution: Don't use this - seriously

**Angular is not jQuery.**

As par as your question is concerned you can use `$element` in your controller(if you are not concrete with the `$scope` usage for this use case) -

```
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $element){
   alert($element.find('form').attr('name')); 
   $scope.myFormName = $element.find('form').attr('name');
});
```

[PLNKR DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/cWhuR6p0xjA49RbbSoOi?p=preview)

Comment: This is an excellent answer, because even if this is not the way to do things, it's clearly the way to LEARN things